# List all db from an mysql server with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Is it possible to list all databases available on a mysql server with c#?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/274/display-a-list-of-databases-on-a-mysql-server/) help? I would try to execute it with the [OleDB.NET provider for MySQL](https://cherrycitysoftware.com/CCS/Providers/ProvMySQL.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, with the query `show databases` (only for mysql) and with ADO.NET to execute and fetch the results in c#, it is very easy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Executing the string "show databases" as a query will return a list of databases which you could work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Sql query for sys.databases I believe.

Comment: This one is only for Microsoft SQL Server ;)

Comment: @Xavinou : You are correct I could have sworn that said mssql instead of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

`show databases` is the quick/dirty method. But in recent MySQL versions, there's the `information_schema` database, which contains metadata about MySQL, including the databases it hosts:

```
select SCHEMA_NAME from information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

will return the name of all defined databases.